# how to rotate a bitmap image

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4, qt5

I receive 800 by 600 by 3 bitmap image and give as a parameter to glDrawPixels(). Before giving this to glDrawPixels, I want to rotate the bitmap by 90 degrees. is that possible?

in case it was not a bitmap and instead an image like png, I would do the following:

```
QMatrix rm;

rm.rotate(90);

pixmap = pixmap.transformed(rm);

pixmap.scaled(801, 701);

texture = bindTexture(pixmap);
```

Comment: You can't give a QPixmap as a parameter of glDrawPixels. What's your *actual* code?

Comment: QMatrix is obsolete, use QTransform instead.

Comment: Yes, I know that, imagine I have an array of BGR, before passing it to glDrawPixels, how can i rotate it by 90 degrees?

Answer (score 11):

```
QImage srcImg(":/icon.png");
QPoint center = srcImg.rect().center();
QMatrix matrix;
matrix.translate(center.x(), center.y());
matrix.rotate(90);
QImage dstImg = srcImge.transformed(matrix);
QPixmap dstPix = QPixmap::fromImage(dstImg);
```

Comment: As I mentioned this is not what I am looking for. I have an array of 8000 by 600 by 3 BGR raw data. before giving this to glDrawPixels, I want to rotate it, but how?

Comment: once again i note the array contains raw image data with no header, the above code is for image with png header.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by liuyi.luo, the normal way of doing this is by using `QImage` and passing in the raw data with the required format, before transforming.

Unfortunately Qt does not support BGR channel order.  You will have to find a third-party library, or roll your own algorithm - which should be pretty trivial if you are rotating by 90degs.  [Here](http://tristan-interview.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/rotate-image-90-degree-clockwise.html)'s a decent implementation of in-place rotation.

Comment: This way is tricky, but I do not understand it completely. I receive a 800 by  600 by 3 packet and append it to an array, until it reads exactly the bitmap size. Next, I am dealing with an array of 800 by 600 by 3 now, how am I supposed to swap its columns and rows!

Comment: Ignore my guess at an implementation, it wouldn't work at all!  I've edited in a link to a tried and tested one.